# Improvement of transfer speed over afp shares

Tags: macos, networking, hard-drive, performance

I was performing speed tests on my upgraded network, and i'm not getting all the speed i thought i could get across network shares. The tests i did between machines A and B (both running OSX Yosemite,  with gigabit ethernet cards):

```
iperf between A and B (tested both directions) ~974 mbit/s
copy a file via smb share, both directions, ~96 mbit/s
copy a file via afp share, both directions, ~464 mbit/s

Machine A hard disk speed r/w  ~600 mbit/s
Machine B hard disk speed r/w  ~800 mbit/s
```

(Hard disk speeds measured with BlackMagick hard disk speed test)

Are those numbers normal for afp shares? I tought the limit would be set by the disks' speed, but it seems there's margin to improve it, as the transfer speed never improves over 464 mbit/s.

Is this something that can be improved tunning some network parameter? Or i have to assume this is the "real life" speed of the disks?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know the answer to why AFP performance (464 Mb/s) is not keeping up with the raw disk speed (600-800 Mb/s).  But, I'm curious if anyone else happens to know why SMB is *so* much slower than AFP?

Comment: I'm curious too... I happened to discover this because ox changed at some point in time that shares default to afp, and now both are selected, and for some reason, smb "wins", even between 2 osx.